# Add a simple link to set a boolean field in Rails - nothing seems to happen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'm trying to add a link to a Rails view to set a boolean field to true when it is clicked. In the controller (present_controller.rb) I have the following code:

```
def taken_toggle
  @matching = Present.find(params[:id])
  @matching.taken = true
  @matching.save
end
```

and in the associated view I have the following code:

```
<%= link_to "I want to buy this present", :url => {:action => "taken_toggle", :id => @present.id} %>
```

However, when I click the button nothing happens. If I go back to the main list the boolean field has not been updated. In the log I get the following:

```
Started GET "/presents/2/edit?url[action]=taken_toggle&url[id]=2" for 152.78.101.154 at Sun Jan 30 04:56:34 -0800 2011
  Processing by PresentsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"url"=>{"action"=>"taken_toggle", "id"=>"2"}, "id"=>"2"}
Rendered presents/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
Rendered presents/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple - does anyone know what it is?

**Update:** I've added the route and `rake routes` is now giving the following line (amongst all the normal routes):

```
taken_toggle_present PUT    /presents/:id/taken_toggle(.:format) {:controller=>"presents", :action=>"taken_toggle"}
```

What should I change the link to so as to make it work? At the moment the link is still:

```
<%= link_to "I want to buy this present", :url => {:action => "taken_toggle", :id => @present.id} %>
```

But that seems right to me, as it is going to the right action, and passing in the ID. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I've tried the latest answers, but both of them lead to the following log error:

```
Started GET "/presents/2/taken_toggle" for 86.150.141.2 at Fri Feb 04 01:37:23 -0800 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/presents/2/taken_toggle"):
```

This seems slightly strange given the output of `rake routes` above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to` doesn't accept a `:url` option, so it's translating everything in your `:url` hash to GET parameters: you can see them in the request path in your logs:

```
GET "/presents/2/edit?url[action]=taken_toggle&url[id]=2"
```

You should just be able to take out the `:url => { }` part to make the link work:

```
link_to "I want to buy this present", :action => "taken_toggle", :id => @present.id
```

However, in general the preferred way to specify a link to a restful action is using a [path helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls):

```
link_to "I want to buy this present", taken_toggle_present_path(@present)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds about right, but I get a routing error (see update to the question above). Any ideas?

Comment: Add to routes.rb this line `match 'presents/:id/taken_toggle' => 'presents/taken_toggle', :as => 'taken_toggle_present'`

Comment: Thanks @Nikita - but that gives me an error saying "missing :action" - have you any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Nikita I managed to fix this by changing `presents/taken_toggle' to `presents#taken_toggle'

Comment: @robintw - Sorry, my typo. Great that you sorted it out )

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're on a rails 3 app. Getting methods (GET, PUT) and routes right should work.

The routes part, either define taken_toggle in the presents resource, like this:

```
resources :presents do
  member do
    put :taken_toggle
  end
end
```

or just use match as Nikita has suggested:

```
match 'presents/:id/taken_toggle', :as => "taken_toggle_present",
  :to => "presents#taken_toggle"
```

Now the link part:

`<%= link_to "I want to buy this present", taken_toggle_present_path(@present), :method => :put %>`

Answer (score 3):

Your route is expecting a PUT request. Try this:

```
<%= link_to "I want to buy this present", taken_toggle_present_path(@present), :method => :put %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done this but get an error about routing - see the update to the question above - it must be something stupid I've done!

Comment: Your error shows you are still doing a get request. Did you specify the `:method` as @dmarkow suggests?

Answer (score 1):

Open your shell and run `rake routes`; you should see the restful route for `taken_toggle` action.

If you can't find it, you want to [add your new restful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). Run `rake routes` again.

Use that route in your link.

---

Consider to switch from GET to POST since that action changes the state of your data.

Comment: PUT is probably better since it appears to be updating the state of an existing object

Comment: Thanks. I've added the route using PUT, but I'm not sure how to change the link - I've posted an update to the question about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a PUT route you should create a form with PUT as method to perform this action.

Though it might go against the REST paradigm I'd recommend creating a GET route if you'd like to perform this action with a simple link. Do not that any hit on that link will change the objects state.